# Comparing two observableLists in Junit

Tags: java, junit, javafx, observablecollection, observablelist

I've tried to check whether two lists are the same using assertEquals and this works just fine but when tried to change the lists to observableList, the test failed.

So how can I compare two observable lists in JUnit? I would like to compare only the content of the lists. Basically, these observableLists contain Point objects and in the Point class I've got hashCodeBuilder and equalsBuilder methods. The `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods were needed for the list comparison but I'm not sure whether they are needed for the ObservableList.

```
public class TestClass {
    private MyClass myclass;
    ObservableList<Point> TestPoints = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        myclass = new MyClass();

        TestPoints.add(new Point(300.0,200.0));
        TestPoints.add(new Point(600.0,500.0));
        TestPoints.add(new Point(100.0,100.0));
        TestPoints.add(new Point(200.0,200.0));
        TestPoints.add(new Point(100.0,500.0));
        TestPoints.add(new Point(600.0,100.0));
    }

    @Test
    public void testClass() {
        ObservableList<Point> expectedResult = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        expectedResult.add(new Point(100.0,100.0));
        expectedResult.add(new Point(100.0,500.0));
        expectedResult.add(new Point(600.0,500.0));
        expectedResult.add(new Point(600.0,100.0));

        ObservableList<Point> actualResult = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        actualResult = myclass.giftWrapping(TestPoints);

        assertEquals(expectedResult, actualResult);
    }
```

This is the point class

```
public class Point {

    private final DoubleProperty x;
    private final DoubleProperty y;

    public Point() {
        this(0, 0);
    }

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = new SimpleDoubleProperty(x);
        this.y = new SimpleDoubleProperty(y);
    }
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    HashCodeBuilder hashCodeBuilder = new HashCodeBuilder();
    hashCodeBuilder.append(x);
    hashCodeBuilder.append(y);
    return hashCodeBuilder.toHashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof Point)) {
        return false;
    }
    Point other = (Point) obj;
    EqualsBuilder equalsBuilder = new EqualsBuilder();
    equalsBuilder.append(x, other.x);
    equalsBuilder.append(y, other.y);
    return equalsBuilder.isEquals();
}
```

This would work if i used a List but doesn't not work if i Used an observableList

Comment: Are you interested in comparing only the content of the lists or do you also want to compare the change listeners or bindings setup which observe the list?

Comment: If you just want to compare the current contents of the lists, `assertEquals` should work just fine for that. Unless you have an implementation of `ObservableList` that does not override `equals` properly. Where do your `ObservableList`s come from?

Comment: I would like to compare only the content of the lists. Basically, these observableLists contain Point objects and in the point class I've got hashCodeBuilder and equalsBuilder methods. The hashCode and equals(0 methods were needed for the list comparison but I'm not sure whether they are needed for the ObservableList

Comment: @Sammson Can you please present a **minimal** example in your question that doesn't assert equal correctly?

Comment: Hello Duncan, I editted the question and added the Junit code

Comment: @Sammson That doesn't compile. `private Class class;` is not a valid statement. And you haven't defined what `Class` is (note: *terrible* name for a class). Also, what type is `Point` exactly? Given that you supply double values to it, I guess it's not `java.awt.Point`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the problem to this question was in the equals and hashCode methods. The variable x and the variable y had to be converted into doubles as they are initially of type DoubleProperty. So the equals and hashCode methods in the Point class should be as follows

```
@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        HashCodeBuilder hashCodeBuilder = new HashCodeBuilder();
        hashCodeBuilder.append(x.doubleValue());
        hashCodeBuilder.append(y.doubleValue());
        return hashCodeBuilder.toHashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Point)) {
            return false;
        }
        Point other = (Point) obj;
        EqualsBuilder equalsBuilder = new EqualsBuilder();
        equalsBuilder.append(x.doubleValue(), other.x.doubleValue());
        equalsBuilder.append(y.doubleValue(), other.y.doubleValue());
        return equalsBuilder.isEquals();
    }
```

This will enable the test to pass